# Fixing a bad pull request

Tags: git, github

I branched a friend's master repo, made some commits, then made a pull request.

There were a number of problems with my request:

One, the commit style was incorrect.

Two, some of the code was bad.

Three, apparently I need to do a rebase the pull request instead of a merge.

I have fixed all of the code, but I'm scared to commit it to my branch; do I need to force push it or something? Further, how do I fix the other issues?

The PR in question: https://github.com/jleclanche/fireplace/pull/344

```
daniel.bak@STPC039 ~/documents/github/fireplace (master)
$ git rebase jleclanche/master
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: Corrupted Healbot + test
Applying: Implemented Bilefine Tidehunter & Zealous Initiat
Applying: Fixing Zealous Initiate name
Applying: Corrupted Seer
Applying: Implement Shadow Strike

daniel.bak@STPC039 ~/documents/github/fireplace (master)
$ git rebase -i jleclance/master
fatal: Needed a single revision
invalid upstream jleclance/master

daniel.bak@STPC039 ~/documents/github/fireplace (master)
$ git rebase -i jleclance/master
fatal: Needed a single revision
invalid upstream jleclance/master

daniel.bak@STPC039 ~/documents/github/fireplace (master)
```

more:

```
daniel.bak@STPC039 ~/documents/github/fireplace (master)
$ git log jleclanche/master
commit 644c375b065c10edd02b8ba2450842404971919a
Author: Jerome Leclanche <jerome@leclan.ch>
Date:   Fri Apr 29 14:26:39 2016 +0300

    Implement Silithid Swarmer, with tests

commit 1f33e4888cdbdec159e932ab4259b9e4f015adc8
Author: Jerome Leclanche <jerome@leclan.ch>
Date:   Fri Apr 29 13:20:57 2016 +0300

    Add a NUM_ATTACKS_THIS_TURN attribute selector

commit 13b58c2ee4249c4195416d257213cf1c4e0a276c
daniel.bak@STPC039 ~/documents/github/fireplace (master)
:

    Implement buff-based enrage from 12051

commit 72b95d2bff4c1af5b2be0331ce6c8b2266298d52
Author: Jerome Leclanche <jerome@leclan.ch>
Date:   Tue Apr 26 06:53:49 2016 +0300

    Add tests for Dalaran Aspirant
```

Comment: How did you conclude 3?

Comment: I was told so, lol. I believe it's because my pull request includes a merge commit.

Comment: Could you link to the pull request, please?

Answer (score 4):

Unless the project has some extra requirements, and a lot of them do, if you need to fix a coding mistake in your PR all you should need to do is commit and push your changes to your existing branch. They should appear as updates in the pull request.

[Here's an example of a pull request that needed some fixups](https://github.com/evalEmpire/perl5i/pull/216). You can see my inline commentary on the initial pull request (flattened into the pull request) and the original submitter update commits.

Your case is different. They have two issues with your commit and they both are Git style nit-picks.

The first is they don't want to see any merges in your PR.  Your history looks something like this:

```
1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 [jleclanche/master]
         \           \
          A - B - C - D - E - F [feature/wog_cards]
```

Having merges in the middle of branches can make it difficult to understand the history in large projects with a lot of contributions. They want you to redo the entire branch as if it was all done on top of the latest commit.

```
1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 [jleclanche/master]
                     \
                      A - B - C - D - E - F [feature/wog_cards]
```

Fortunately, Git can do this for you.  First, make sure the `jleclanche` remote is up to date with a fetch.  Then checkout `feature/wog_cards` (or whatever your branch is called) and run `git rebase jleclanche/master`.

- `git fetch jleclanche`
- `git checkout feature/wog_cards`
- `git rebase jleclanche/master`

This will repatch each change in your branch on top of `jleclanche/master`. There may be conflicts, resolve them as normal and follow the instructions git gives you (ie. use `git rebase --continue`).

Once that's done, you can also use `rebase` to fix your commit messages to follow their style guide. This time it's an interactive rebase. This lets you edit your commits. From your branch run `git rebase -i jleclanche/master`. It will bring up an editor with instructions. You want to use the "reword" option on each commit. Git will present you with each commit message in turn and you should edit them to follow [their style guide](https://github.com/jleclanche/fireplace/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md).

[Here's some more information about rewriting history](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History).

Finally you need to push these changes.  Because you've changed history your changes cannot go cleanly on top of your existing commits.  So you have to force push.  In this case it's fine, the only repository you can mess up is your own. `git push --force origin`.  Then your changes should show up in the PR.

As you can see, this involves some fairly advanced knowledge of Git. IMO custodial fixes to contributions by first time contributors should be taken care of by the project.

Comment: The project has commit requirements, which my commits did not fulfil.

Comment: @DanielPaczuskiBak I see now, this is going to require rebasing.

Comment: @DanielPaczuskiBak Ok, updated based on what's in the PR.

Comment: Tried to follow your instructions; console is in the main question. Thanks a ton.

Also have a clarification: what do I do with my code modifications? Do I stash them? That's what I did but I'm not sure.

I can change my commit style stuff, but that won't fix the code, right? Do I just push additional commits on top to rectify the commits that now have good style but bad code?

Comment: @DanielPaczuskiBak That's weird. Check what ID `jleclance/master` is. It should be `644c375b065c10edd02b8ba2450842404971919a`. Check with `git log jleclance/master`. As for the code fixes, yes, just commit them like normal.

Comment: I've added that stuff.

I was told that a previous fix needed to be a fixup and not a commit, does that change our strategy here at all?

Comment: @DanielPaczuskiBak At this point I'd suggest you tell them you don't know git well enough to be doing all this and ask them for help. They have an IRC channel you can join.

Comment: I read up on fixup. Do you have any idea why the rebase says I need a single revision?

Comment: @DanielPaczuskiBak `invalid upstream jleclance/master` means your branch is not a branch of `jleclance/master`. That is, you spelt it wrong. :)

Answer (score 0):

After you fixed your local branch to have the history you / they want, just force-push to the PR branch and the PR will be updated automatically with the replaced commits.